# SQL Recursive Getting Records From Selected Node and Above as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, treeview, recursive-query

Example table:

```
id  name    manager_id
1   Alice   NULL
2   Bob 1
3   Charlie 2
4   David   3
5   Eve 1
6   Frank   5
```

When the id number 4 is selected in the table, I want to get the id number 4 and the records above it as xml in the tree structure.
The output should look like the following.
In other words, the selected Id and the nodes above it come as xml in the tree structure.

[The image I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP0Bm.jpg)

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChildOrganisations (@ParentID INT)
    RETURNS XML
    AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 
        (
            SELECT  id [@OrgID],
                    name [@Name],
                    manager_id [@Index],
                    dbo.GetChildOrganisations(manager_id) [ChildOrganisations] 
            FROM    employees 
            WHERE   id = @ParentID
            FOR XML PATH('Orgainisations')
        )
    END
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: there is a recursive CTE available for such problems

Comment: @nbk Recursive CTE is almost impossible to use for recursive aggregation, a self-referencing function is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to remove the column name from `ChildOrganisations`, so that the inner XML is directly embedded.

You also need to change/remove columns as necessary, and change the `PATH` parameter to match what you want.

You should also use `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`, and a `CASE` so that you don't endlessly call the same function.

Also you should use `, TYPE` to avoid conversion problems.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChildOrganisations (@ParentID INT)
RETURNS XML
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT  name [@Text]
                CASE WHEN manager_id IS NOT NULL THEN dbo.GetChildOrganisations(manager_id) END
        FROM    employees 
        WHERE   id = @ParentID
        FOR XML PATH('TreeViewNode'), TYPE
    );
END;
```

Then you can call it like this

```sql
SELECT dbo.GetChildOrganisations(4)
FOR XML PATH('Nodes'), TYPE;
```

Comment: the result
<Organisations>
  <Organisation OrgID="4" Name="David" Index="3">
    <Organisation OrgID="3" Name="Charlie" Index="2">
      <Organisation OrgID="2" Name="Bob" Index="1">
        <Organisation OrgID="1" Name="Alice" />
      </Organisation>
    </Organisation>
  </Organisation>
</Organisations>

what i want:
<Nodes>
 <TreeViewNode Text="Alice"  >
  <TreeViewNode Text="Bob" >
   <TreeViewNode Text="Charlie">
    <TreeViewNode Text="David"/>
   </TreeViewNode>
  </TreeViewNode>
 </TreeViewNode>
</Nodes>

Comment: Well then just change the columns and `PATH` to match. See edit

Answer (score -1):

Based on the given table structure and desired output, you can use the following query to generate the XML tree structure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChildOrganisations (@ParentID INT)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT  id [@OrgID],
                name [@Name],
                manager_id [@Index],
                dbo.GetChildOrganisations(manager_id) [ChildOrganisations] 
        FROM    employees 
        WHERE   id <= @ParentID
        FOR XML PATH('Organisation'), TYPE
    )
END
```

This function recursively retrieves the records from the employee's table, starting from the given @ParentID and working its way up to the root. The FOR XML PATH clause is used to generate the XML structure, with each record represented as an  element.

To use this function and obtain the desired output for ID 4, you can execute the following query:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml = dbo.GetChildOrganisations(4);

SELECT @xml;
```

Comment: SQL is not HTML... please don't make it a HTML snippet.

Comment: This smells GPT generated to me, if I am honest, @DaleK .

Comment: True... Good call